# Making legends specific to graphs within a figure using ggplot2 and gridExtra in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have the following plot:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), col2 = rnorm(12), col3 = runif(12), col4 = rep(c("Fred", "Bob"), each = 6))
df1_list <- split(df1, df1$col1)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = mapply(function (x, y) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(x, ggplot2::aes(x = col2, y = col3, col = col4)) +
    ggplot2::geom_point() +
    ggplot2::ggtitle(y) +
    ggplot2::scale_color_manual('Person', values = c('Fred' = 'red', 'Bob' = 'blue'))
}, x = df1_list, y = names(df1_list), SIMPLIFY = F))
```

[image]

On the first graph in this figure, all the points represent `Fred`, but in the legend, `Bob` still appears. Is it possible to include only the people who appear in each graph in the legend?

I want to make sure `'Fred'` is always `'red'` and `'Bob'` is always `'blue'`, so using the `scale_discrete_manual` function's `drop = T` argument won't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution where the `values` parameter in `scale_color_manual` is dynamically created.

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), col2 = rnorm(12), 
             col3 = runif(12), col4 = rep(c("Fred", "Bob"), each = 6))
df1$col4 <- factor(df1$col4)
df1_list <- split(df1, df1$col1)
cols <- setNames(c('red', 'blue'), c('Fred','Bob'))
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = mapply(function (x, y) {
  x$col4 <- droplevels(x$col4)
  idx <- match(levels(x$col4), names(cols))
  ggplot2::ggplot(x, ggplot2::aes(x = col2, y = col3, col = col4)) +
    ggplot2::geom_point() +
    ggplot2::ggtitle(y) +
    ggplot2::scale_color_manual('Person', values = cols[idx])
}, x = df1_list, y = names(df1_list), SIMPLIFY = F))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your `sessionInfo()` so we can see the package versions you run? I run your code and this is what I get.

[image]

Comment: gridExtra_2.3       ggplot2_3.3.5

Comment: I am running same gridExtra version but  ggplot2_3.3.2